# Should CMS systems use a message queue architecture?

Tags: content-management-system, rabbitmq, message-queue

Recently, I have been dabbling in Content Management Systems, and reading some "lessons learned" from twitter, one of their major bottlenecks was that they were not using a message queue system in the beginning. Right now, my CMS doesn't use a message queue architecture, but more and more, I'm seeing the benefits of it. So I've been wondering, should I use a message queue system, and if so, how much of the functionality should  live in it (i.e. content publishing, notifications, etc.)?

Comment: Can you share your own experience with message queue pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few good reasons to use a message queue.  1. They make a good front end to an unstable system.  If the system is down, the action can still be captured.  2. Throttling - Actions coming in too fast for a system to handle, but need to be recorded and their handling delayed. 3. Event triggering: if multiple services need to react to a single client event, have the message queue system take care of this communication. 4. Help processing events asynchronously.

I don't see content publishing benefiting from a message queue.  Sounds like something that should be done synchronously anyway.  Notifications, however, might be a good fit.